# PyQt4 Adjust QCombobox after select() update from QSqlTableModel

Tags: python, pyqt4, qcombobox, qsizepolicy

I am getting the model to update the content items of the QCombobox, but I cannot seem to get the combo box to adjust to contents, even after I established that directive when setting up the QCombobox widget. After the model updates, the combo box remains the same width, and does not adjust to fit the text content, and the longer text strings get truncated until I restart the application. How do you dynamically adjust the dimensions of a QCombobox, based on the content of the model?

Here's the combo box:

```
def build(self):
    self.comboStns = QComboBox()
    self.comboStns.setModel(self.model)
    self.comboStns.setModelColumn(self.model.fieldIndex("title"))
    self.layout.addWidget(self.comboStns, 0, 0)
    self.btnAddStn = QPushButton("Add Station")
    self.btnAddStn.clicked.connect(self.openAddStns)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.btnAddStn, 0, 1)
    self.dialogAddStn = StationsDialog(self)
```

This is the dialog window that updates the model of the combo box:

```
def addStation(self):
    stnMetaName = self.txtStnName.text().toLower()
    stnMetaName = stnMetaName.replace(QRegExp("[\W]+"), "_")
    query = QSqlQuery()
    query.prepare("INSERT INTO stations (meta_name, title) VALUES (:meta, :title)")
    query.bindValue(":meta", stnMetaName)
    query.bindValue(":title", self.txtStnName.text())
    query.exec_()
    # back to the parent window model which hosts the combobox
    self.parent().model.select()
    self.close()
```

Comment: FYI: I have taken a shot at the size policy methods, but either I don't understand how they work, or I am applying them in the wrong way.